# Sphinx or Thinking Sphinx not returning entries I know are present

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to get Sphinx 2.1.7 working with Rails 3.2.17 app running on Ruby 1.9.3p448 on Mac OS 10.8.5. I'm using MySQL 5.1.71. I'm using the [Thinking Sphinx gem 3.1.1](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx).

I have a model called `Entry` and I'd like to search on columns `entries.title` and `entries.entry` (Yeah, the column containing the "content" of the `Entry` is called `entry`.)

I followed the Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx docs closely as I could.

Here's my setup...

### Index definition...

`entry_index.rb`

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define(
  :entry, :with => :active_record, :delta => true
  ) do

  indexes(title)
  indexes(entry)

  has user_id
  has created_at
  has updated_at

end
```

The `entries` table has a column...

```
`delta` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
```

### Thinking Sphinx config...

`thinking_sphinx.yml`

```
defaults: &defaults
  bin_path: '/usr/local/bin'
  morphology: stem_en
  enable_star: 1
  min_word_len: 3
  min_prefix_len: 2
  min_infix_len: 2
  expand_keywords: 1
  index_exact_words: 1
  mem_limit: 512M

development:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

### What's going wrong...

What's going wrong is that I'll create a new `Entry`, for example...

> **Title:** This is not the only Entry where I mention persimmons
>
> **Entry:** I like persimmons.

Then I'll run a search and a few previous entries (from months ago) come up that contain "persimmon," but not the new one I just created.

I then shut down my app and run...

```
bundle exec rake ts:rebuild
```

And try again.

The new "persimmon" entry still doesn't come up.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

### Sphinx not reporting that it's rebuilding the index

When I rebuild, I get the output below. I'm used to seeing something like "rebuilding indexes," but that isn't happening. I'm thinking thing might have something to do with it?

```
$ bundle exec rake ts:rebuild
Stopped searchd daemon (pid: 1976).
Generating configuration to /Users/username/Dropbox/project-dropbox/journal_application/config/development.sphinx.conf
Started searchd successfully (pid: 2007).
```

### Sphinx config file

Here is the `development.sphinx.conf` generated by thinking Sphinx...

```
indexer
{
  mem_limit = 512M
}

searchd
{
  listen = 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
  log = /Users/username/Dropbox/project-dropbox/journal_application/log/development.searchd.log
  query_log = /Users/username/Dropbox/project-dropbox/journal_application/log/development.searchd.query.log
  pid_file = /Users/username/Dropbox/project-dropbox/journal_application/log/development.sphinx.pid
  workers = threads
  binlog_path = /Users/username/Dropbox/project-dropbox/journal_application/tmp/binlog/development
}

source entry_core_0
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = localhost
  sql_user = root
  sql_pass = 
  sql_db = journal_app_development
  sql_query_pre = SET TIME_ZONE = '+0:00'
  sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
  sql_query = SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `entries`.`id` * 3 + 0 AS `id`, `entries`.`title` AS `title`, `entries`.`entry` AS `entry`, `entries`.`id` AS `sphinx_internal_id`, 'Entry' AS `sphinx_internal_class`, 0 AS `sphinx_deleted`, `entries`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`entries`.`created_at`) AS `created_at`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`entries`.`updated_at`) AS `updated_at` FROM `entries`  WHERE (`entries`.`id` BETWEEN $start AND $end) GROUP BY `entries`.`id`, `entries`.`title`, `entries`.`entry`, `entries`.`id`, `entries`.`user_id`, `entries`.`created_at`, `entries`.`updated_at` ORDER BY NULL
  sql_query_range = SELECT IFNULL(MIN(`entries`.`id`), 1), IFNULL(MAX(`entries`.`id`), 1) FROM `entries` 
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  sql_attr_uint = user_id
  sql_attr_timestamp = created_at
  sql_attr_timestamp = updated_at
  sql_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  sql_query_post_index = UPDATE `entries` SET `delta` = 0 WHERE `delta` = 1
  sql_query_info = SELECT `entries`.* FROM `entries`  WHERE (`entries`.`id` = ($id - 0) / 3)
}

index entry_core
{
  type = plain
  path = /Users/username/Dropbox/project-dropbox/journal_application/db/sphinx/development/entry_core
  docinfo = extern
  morphology = stem_en
  min_word_len = 3
  charset_type = utf-8
  min_prefix_len = 2
  min_infix_len = 2
  enable_star = 1
  expand_keywords = 1
  index_exact_words = 1
  source = entry_core_0
}

source entry_delta_0
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = localhost
  sql_user = root
  sql_pass = 
  sql_db = journal_app_development
  sql_query_pre = SET TIME_ZONE = '+0:00'
  sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
  sql_query = SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `entries`.`id` * 3 + 0 AS `id`, `entries`.`title` AS `title`, `entries`.`entry` AS `entry`, `entries`.`id` AS `sphinx_internal_id`, 'Entry' AS `sphinx_internal_class`, 0 AS `sphinx_deleted`, `entries`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`entries`.`created_at`) AS `created_at`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`entries`.`updated_at`) AS `updated_at` FROM `entries`  WHERE (`entries`.`delta` = 1 AND `entries`.`id` BETWEEN $start AND $end) GROUP BY `entries`.`id`, `entries`.`title`, `entries`.`entry`, `entries`.`id`, `entries`.`user_id`, `entries`.`created_at`, `entries`.`updated_at` ORDER BY NULL
  sql_query_range = SELECT IFNULL(MIN(`entries`.`id`), 1), IFNULL(MAX(`entries`.`id`), 1) FROM `entries`  WHERE (`entries`.`delta` = 1)
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  sql_attr_uint = user_id
  sql_attr_timestamp = created_at
  sql_attr_timestamp = updated_at
  sql_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
  sql_query_info = SELECT `entries`.* FROM `entries`  WHERE (`entries`.`id` = ($id - 0) / 3)
}

index entry_delta
{
  type = plain
  path = /Users/username/Dropbox/project-dropbox/journal_application/db/sphinx/development/entry_delta
  docinfo = extern
  morphology = stem_en
  min_word_len = 3
  charset_type = utf-8
  min_prefix_len = 2
  min_infix_len = 2
  enable_star = 1
  expand_keywords = 1
  index_exact_words = 1
  source = entry_delta_0
}

index entry
{
  type = distributed
  local = entry_core
  local = entry_delta
}
```

Comment: What's the output when you run the ts:rebuild task?